# How to find the maximum span of a given array of numbers?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

The problem I am trying to solve is the following : I want to find a maximum span of numbers in a given array that is given an array A consisting of both positive and negative integers return the largest (A[j] - A[i]) such that 1<= i < j <= n, and I came up with the following nlogn time algorithm for this problem -:

1. find the index of the nth order statistic of the array let it be "i"
2. find the index of the 1st order statistic of the array let it be "j"
3. if i > j, then return the difference because we found the difference between the maximum and the minimum elements of the array and hence just terminate returning the difference.
4. if j > i then divide the array into two halves and find the maximum span in the 2 halves i.e A[1....i] and A[i + 1 ...... n] by calling this algorithm recursively, the case being when the algorithm finds such a pair i,j it returns the difference between those pairs, otherwise it keeps recursing and in the end terminates.
5. return the maximum{max_span of subarray 1 , max_span of subarray2}

This algorithm is O(nlogn) but I don't know if its correct or not.

Comment: So if you count "span", you just want to count the difference between Max and Min number in that array?

Comment: Ah I probably get it, so it is Max and Min, but the Min must be always be "on the left"

Comment: yes the min must always be on the left A[j] - A[i] 1 <= i < j <= n

Comment: I think your alghoritm is wrong what about {9,-5,-4,6,7,8}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum single-sell profit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086464/maximum-single-sell-profit)

Comment: This is the maximum single-sell profit problem, which I believe has already been solved here before.

Answer (score 3):

@mrip solution's complexity is O(n) in time and O(n) in space. It is correct, however only O(1) space complexity is enough for this problem.

```
int min=a[0],ans=0;
for (int i=1;i<n;i++)
    if (a[i]<min) min=a[i];
    else ans=max(ans,a[i]-min);
return ans;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an O(n) algorithm.

1. Build an array Max where Max[i] is the maximum of A[k] for k>=i.  This can be done in O(n) time by iterating through A backwards.
2. Build an array Min where Min[i] is the minimum of A[k] for k<=i.  Again O(n).
3. Iterate through Max and Min to find the index i that maximizes Max[i]-Min[i].  Also O(n).
4. Return (Min[i],Max[i]).

On edit: there is a corner case, where the array is in reverse sorted order, in which case Max[i]=Min[i]=A[i] for all i.  This can be detected in O(n) time, and in this case, you just return the pair of adjacent elements that maximize A[i+1]-A[i] (which will be negative).

Comment: I believe it is correct (but I'm not positive).  However, it's not O(nlogn).  In the worst case, it's n^2.  It will be O(nlogn) if i is always near the middle of the array, but there is no guarantee of this, and, unlike quicksort, there's no (obvious) way to randomize it.

Comment: Are you sure that the step 3. if O(n)?

Comment: @libik Pretty sure.  You just need to iterate through once.  Why would you think it takes longer?

Comment: mrip : yeah, true, now I see this... you are genious :D