# Optimal solution for the maximum single sell profit algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, nested-loops

The input array is:

```
A[0] = 23171 
A[1] = 21015 
A[2] = 21123
A[3] = 21366 
A[4] = 21013 
A[5] = 21367
```

Mission is to find maximum profit. E.g A[3] - A[2] = 243
and my code is:

```
class Solution {
    int profit = 0;
    public int solution(int[] A) {
         for (int i = 0;i < A.length; i++){
            for (int j = i + 1; j < A.length; j++){
                if(A[j] - A[i] > profit)
                    profit = A[j] - A[i];
            }
         }
         return profit;
   }
}
```

The result is suppose to be 365 but it blows up on larger inputs.
This code has a time complexity of O(N<sup>2</sup>) but is possible to do with O(N). I can't really see how to avoid nesting here... Any pointers in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: How large is "large" input? And what do you mean by "blows up"?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Biggest difference between 2 entries?

Comment: It blows up on inputs between 10k -200k.

Comment: Are you looking for the answer for the **max - min**? for the best accepted answer did it for you. if not, take care of your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum single-sell profit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086464/maximum-single-sell-profit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that most of you got it wrong. The problem in the post is the **maximum single sell profit problem** which is a typical interview question.

**The most optimal solution**:

```
    public int dynamicProgrammingSingleSellProfit(int[] arr) {
        if(arr.length == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int profit = 0;
        int cheapest = arr[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            cheapest = Math.min(cheapest, arr[i]);
            profit = Math.max(profit, arr[i] - cheapest);

        }
        return profit;
    }
```

It has `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space complexity.

If you examine the original question the op is looking for `profit` and since we can't travel in time *(yet)* you can't just compare the minimum and the maximum in the array.

Comment: Check my comments on the other answers.

Comment: Adam, it is correct that it is an interview test question. You spotted that immediatelly. Is there anywhere where I can read up on this? What does isa mean?

Comment: Search for 'single sell profit problem' on google. There is an exhaustive python solution [here](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=single-sell-profit).

Answer (score 14):

You only need to get max value and min value from your array and substract them both, so in a O(N) iteration, get the min and the max values.

```
class Solution {

    public int solution(int[] A) {

        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        for (int i = 0;i < A.length; i++){
            if(A[i] > max) max = A[i];
            if(A[i] < min) min = A[i];
        }

        return max - min;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 +1 
Wouldn't know any other better *pure* solution than this and its O(n)!

Comment: I read the question and thought about it for a minute, then read this answer and my jaw dropped.  Thumbs up.

Comment: Is the intended output for an empty array `-1`?

Comment: There are no emtpy arrays in this problem.

Comment: In the original implementation, the second index `j` is always bigger than `i` -> `for (int j = i + 1; j < A.length; j++)`. This implementation does not enforce this.

Comment: After rereading the question I realized that you got it wrong. Check my answer. You are scanning the whole array for min and max but while you can't time travel you can't find a **profit** that way.

Comment: If the max comes before the min, this algorithm gives you the wrong answer. Please downvote this.

Comment: @mdenton8 can you elaborate with an example, my algorithm should work in all the scenarios

Comment: "If the max comes before the min, this algorithm gives you the wrong answer". Your algorithm gives the wrong answers in most examples like this. For example, if these are the stock price values: 50, 1, 2, your algorithm calculates that you can make 49 dollars. This is entirely wrong, as you can only make $1 (buy on day 2, sell on day 3), because you can't buy on day 3 and turn around and sell it on day 1 without time travel.

Comment: Notice how the naive double loop starts the inner loop on ``j = i + 1``. Your algorithm just changes this to start on ``j = 0`` and uses the absolute value of ``A[j] - A[i]`` as profit, but there's a reason it wasn't like that in the first place...

Comment: Previous commenters have mentioned these problems. You should edit your answer explaining why it is wrong, it would be useful to future visitors.