# Maximum single-sell profits

Tags: arrays, algorithm, list

The question [Maximum single-sell profit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086464/maximum-single-sell-profit) returns one pair. How can you build upon any of the sub O(n^2) algorithm to find all pairs sorted by profit?

Ex.

```
values: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 5, 10, -5, 0, -10, 15)
pairsAsc: Vector[(Int, Int)] = Vector((5,6), (3,6), (0,6), (0,2), (3,4))
gains: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(25, 20, 14, 9, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's [Sorting-X+Y-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_%2B_Y_sorting), so it's unreasonable to expect an o(n^2 log n)-time algorithm (in some reasonable model of computation).

The reduction is, given arrays x<sub>1</sub>, … x<sub>n</sub> > 0 and y<sub>1</sub>, … y<sub>n</sub> > 0, let Z > max(x<sub>1</sub>, … x<sub>n</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>, … y<sub>n</sub>). Let the input to this problem be Z - x<sub>1</sub>, …, Z - x<sub>n</sub>, 3Z + y<sub>1</sub>, …, 3Z + y<sub>n</sub>. All of the X-X differences and Y-Y differences are less than Z. All of the X-Y differences are greater than Z. This makes it easy to filter the output, solving the original problem.